How can I deploy my whatsapp bot on Render
I am using whatsapp-web.js to create auto reply bot for my whatsapp when I am in away mode.
If I run d app locally on my PC, it works fine but when I host it on Render as a web service, it does not work.
This is my startApp function
const startApp = async () => {
    if (!process.env.MONGODB_URI) {
        console.error("Error: MONGODB_URI environment variable is not set.");
        process.exit(1);
    }
    try {
        await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI);
        console.log("Connected to MongoDB");
        await client.initialize();
        console.log("WhatsApp Client initialized");
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error starting the app:", error);
        process.exit(1);
    }
};

startApp();

I see the following errors/warnings in render console

Docs on specifying a port: https://render.com/docs/web-services#port-binding
Port scan timeout reached, no open ports detected on 0.0.0.0. Detected open ports on localhost -- did you mean to bind one of these to 0.0.0.0?
Docs on specifying a port: https://render.com/docs/web-services#port-binding
No open ports detected on 0.0.0.0, continuing to scan...
Common ways to troubleshoot your deploy: https://docs.render.com/troubleshooting-deploys
Timed out: Port scan timeout reached, no open ports detected on 0.0.0.0. Detected open ports on localhost -- did you mean to bind one of these to 0.0.0.0?

I dont know how to specify port for the app, I am not using express js.
I tried to host it on render and I expected the auto reply to work
